# Android How to find original apk on the system partition

Tags: java, android, apk

Using PackageManager I've got ApplicationInfo about apps that are filtered by ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP. I know that sourceDir points me to the current apk location, but I also need to get the original system apk location. Is there any non HACK way to do this... or do I have to list all apks on the system and find the right one?

To clarify, let say I have a /data/app/com.google.apps.maps-1/Maps.apk I want to know that this is an update to /system/app/Maps/Base.apk

Answer (score 0):

All apk files can be found in data/app folder on your device, but you need root permission in order to access system files.

Comment: No you don't, at least to list them, even so that is not an answer to my question.